# How to get Hex String of Storage File in Windows Phone 8.1 for pdf

Tags: c#, windows

I am getting images using PhotoChooser and CameraCapture Taks,

I am storing these images in Local Storage and in the form of "PDF Document".

My aim is that, I have to add this document in "Hex String". I am able to convert it into Hex String but not properly.

Because, after adding PDF Document, when I see that document in my phone, it is something other document.

Here is my ByteArray:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)image1.Source);
wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 400, 400, 0, 100);
bytearray = ms.ToArray();
```

Now, creating it to Local Storage:

```
StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Test.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, bytearray);
```

Then trying to Convert it to MemoryStream:

```
MemoryStream itsStream = new MemoryStream();
var outputStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
Stream longStream = outputStream.AsStream();
longStream.CopyTo(itsStream);

byte[] allInOne = itsStream.ToArray()
```

Here is my final HexString of "PDF Document":

```
string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(allInOne);
```

Thanks.